# How to implement cut / Copy / Paste DIV in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net. and I have a div which should be organised in dynamic manner. Meaning I want to organise the div in dynamic manner. My divs are

```
     <div id="LatestReviews" runat="server">
        LatestReviews
    </div>
    <div id="PopularListings" runat="server">
        PopularListings
    </div>
    <div id="Headlines" runat="server">
        Headlines
    </div>
    <div id="LatestEvents" runat="server">
        LatestEvents
    </div>
    <div id="NewJobs" runat="server">
        vNewJobs
    </div>
    <div id="LatestClassifieds" runat="server">
        LatestClassifieds
    </div>
    <div id="NewWishes" runat="server">
        NewWishes
    </div>
    <div id="SalesAndDiscounts" runat="server">
        SalesAndDiscounts
    </div>
```

I want the `LatestClassifieds` should come in first place and  `LatestReviews` to Come in place of `LatestClassifieds` and so on and so forth. I want to do it by C# code. I have a datatable which has the sequence of ordering div for the page. According to the Sequence I want to organise DIV. I Find to cut paste for the textbox but not the asp control. Is there any solution for cut paste Divs in C#?? any solution are surely appretiated.

Comment: How can you have "div"s in your database? Did you mean you have the strings like "NewWishes", "LatestClassifieds", "SalesAnddiscounts", etc., in your database?

Comment: No No I have the order Value for the div by which The div should be placed

Comment: Do you mean your divs are associated with a number value indicating their orders? Say ("NewWishes", 1), ("LatestClassifieds", 2), ("SalesAnddiscounts", 3) and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something else you can try to archive the same;

Add the *Sequence/Priority column* in you DB for each of the category.

Then wile fetching the data for DB short as per Sequence/Priority and then add it to HTML using c# code.

The *advantage* here is that you will be able to change the location/occurrence of any item without changing you code.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: This is what I have in my DB. I have sequence value by which I need to organise the div.

Comment: is LatestClassifieds  Sequence/Priority is 1, have to sorted you data ?

Comment: yes and the `NewWishes` is 2 ,`Headlines`  is 3 and `SalesAndDiscounts` is 4 and so on and so forth...

Comment: So if you sort your data with query and then use resulting dataset to add  DIV at runtime it should do the JOB..!!

Comment: if I Cannot add Div at runtime because inside each div I have repeater and inside Repeater Another Repeater. So I need to keep the repeater Intact.